# Viewport pivot point changed from scene objects to around viewport camera origin

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I am starting to learn using blender, and at some point I managed to do something to the 3D view camera.

Usually the camera orbits around an object, but now the rotation seems to happen (atleast very close to) around the "camera's origin". Neither the input setting in "User Preferences", the pivot point selection nor Ctrl-Alt-Shift-C (as suggested on some forum) do anything to the issue.

Comment: Try `Shift+C` and `Numpad .` (period)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/696/599

Comment: @gandalf3 Both move the camera, but neither of those fixes the pivot. I think the issue is not the "pivot", but that the camera is in a wrong mode of some sorts

Comment: By "camera", do you mean the viewport view or the scene camera object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you centered the view on the camera.
Here are some ways to set the view center:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> or *3D view header > View > [Zoom Border](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View#Zoom_Border)* (Note that this will also zoom to fit the view to the defined border)
- Select an object/vert/face/spline etc. and press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (period) to center the view to the selection.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to center the view to the world origin (default). Note this will also center the *3D cursor*.

If none of these work, then it sounds like you have [*Locked* the view pivot](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects#Object_Centers) to the camera object (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad .</kbd>). See if there is any object  selected in the *Lock to object* option in *3D view > [Properties region](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options#View_Properties_Panel) (<kbd>N</kbd>) > View > Lock to object*:

[image]

You can remove this lock by clicking the *X* next to the object name, or pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad .</kbd>.

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is a shortcut for snapping [object origins](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects#Object_Centers). (it does not affect the view)

Comment: "View -> Lock to object" did the trick. I had somehow specified a (scene) camera there.

Answer (score 3):

Helpful tip here, even though it's already been answered: You can also press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Num .</kbd> to lock it, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Num . to unlock.