# Having trouble with panning in 3D view

Tags: 3d-view

I was modeling something when suddenly I was unable to pan around using shift + middle mouse.  I tried changing the controls in user preferences, closing and reopening the program, and everything else I could think of, all to no avail.  I'm working with 2.69.  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:  Still not sure what happened, but I copied everything in the file into a new one and now it's working.

Comment: restart blender?

Comment: Tried that already.  Nothing.

Comment: Do the shift key and the middle mouse button work elsewhere?

Comment: can you confirm that the buttons still work

Comment: I tried switching the controls for rotate and pan in the preferences, and shift + middle mouse worked fine for rotating and middle mouse still did nothing for panning.  I opened a new file and it worked fine as well, so I don't think it's a problem with the buttons.

Comment: I do not know whats going on over there. Some witchcraft as far as I know. Anyway I would just copy and paste your model into a new file and take it form there.

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: It sounds like you locked your view to an object (see [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3505/599)).