# Zooming in to a selection of vertices with the period key does not work as expected

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I am following through the exercises in BlenderBasics_4thEdition2011.pdf and have gotten to the section on texturing.  The book goes through the creation of a Lighthouse and now I am texturing it.  I want to have a closeup view of the roof of the lighthouse after partitioning it as the lesson describes on page 54.

In order to get a close up view I selected the roof and want to center the screen on the vertices of it so I pressed the <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> key.  When I do that the view zooms so that the roof is off the screen.

What am I am doing wrong?

[image]

I tried Ray's answer and was able to move the origin but pressing the <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> key still did not work.  The centering was still on the bottom of the lighthouse, as if the origin was still there.

[image]

Comment: If you can supply the blend file that will help. Two points: 1. Just to let you know, it can be helpful to comment on an answer if it doesn't work, as that will notify the person who answered, editing a question won't. 2. Editing this question with updated details is sufficient, your other question has been marked as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Without more info or a .blend I don't think there is much we can do besides guess. Voted to close as unclear.

Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3506/599

Answer (score 3):

You can also try using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to activate the box selection zoom tool, now you can drag out a box and the view will zoom to that area.

This works in many modes, so Object, Edit, Paint, Sculpt, etc... but not the UVImage or the Node Editors.

Using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will zoom out to fit the scene so both can be used to quickly zoom in and out of an area.

That being said, if <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>doesn't work for you than you should try resetting Blender to Factory Defaults: 'File->Load Factory Settings'.  Sometimes odd problems like the one you are having are due to some setting that was unknowingly changed.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you accidentally locked the view to an object or to the 3d cursor.

**To unlock the view from object:**

1. Press the <kbd>N</kbd> hotkey to open the properties panel on the right of the 3D view.
2. In the **View** section remove the object in the *Lock to Object* setting. If it is active, the Object name to which the view is locked will be listed in that field.
3. Click the X to the right of the object name to remove it.

**To unlock the view from cursor:**

1. Same as above, open the properties panel scroll down to the **View** section.
2. Uncheck the option *"Lock to Cursor"*.

After unlocking the view, zooming to selection should work as expected.

In the image bellow you can see the correct settings for zooming to start working as expected.
[image: Setting for an unlocked view.]

Answer (score 0):

After reporting something similar as a bug the conclusion was that when assigning  <kbd>F</kbd> as *Focus* you will have to disable the shortcut for *Make Edge/Face* for it work in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: When did you report it as bug? 2015 when this question was asked or now?