# how to? pivot editor camera around object

Tags: 3d-view, camera

How do you rotate around an object with the editor camera instead of orbiting around the center of the scene (middle mouse button).

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/viewport-pivot-point-changed-from-scene-objects-to-around-viewport-camera-origin

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Numpad-.</kbd> makes the selected objects the center of rotation.

If this is not a duplicate question, I will be surprised.