# Pivot Point wont change

Tags: 3d-view

I have a scene with some objects.
Lamps, modelled stuff and imported 3ds objects.

When i try to rotate the 3d View via middlemouse, the pivotpoint is never inside the selected object.
It always sits at the middle of the screen.

Is there a way to force blender to pivot around the selected object ?
Pivot Point settings imply that you can easily tell blender where the pivotpoint should sit.
But if i use it nothing changes.
[image]
Things i already tried:
I reset the origin.
I tried all Pivot Point Settings.
I applied Rotation and Scale.
I looked for already asked questions and answers but none of them helped.

What is it im doing wrong ?
Is there a simple solution and im just stupid ?

Comment: "*What is it im doing wrong ?*" We have absolutely no clue what you are doing at all, wright or wrong. Please edit your question and provide more details and screenshots of your scene.

Comment: edited it and hope its clearer

Comment: Going on new edit, I think OP wants to [align view to object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html#view-panel)  Eg with balloon selected, shift numpad . (period).

Comment: [Pivot point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html) of the object controls how the object will be rotated / transformed around that point and isn't related to the center of the viewport camera rotation, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/696/how-to-reset-the-center-of-rotation-of-the-3d-view-when-it-is-not-the-center-of on how to reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it is the rotation of the 3D view that always pivots around the center of the screen and you would like it to pivot around the selected objects origin instead, you need to activate the "Rotate Around Selection" setting.

File menu > User Preferences > Interface

[image: Blender User Preferences]