# I can't look inside of my models

Tags: modeling

I am a very beginner with blender and I had always the opportunity to zoom inside of my models when im in the edit mode. Now I can zoom as much as I want but never get inside of the model. Can someone maybe help me? this would be really great!
Thank you!
-Chapi

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/696/how-to-reset-the-center-of-rotation-of-the-3d-view-when-it-is-not-the-center-of

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change from Ortographic to Perspective using <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> and try zooming in again.

Look in the top left of the Viewport: if it says `Ortho` you won't be able to see the "inside" of objects, if it says`Persp` you probably will.